# How to populate XML tag dynamically using DataWeave

Tags: dataweave

Below are the required input and output formats:
    **Input XML**:

```
<entity>
        <element>
            <elementName>ProcessName</elementName>
            <elementValue>StepOne</elementValue>
        </element>
</entity>

**Output XML**:
<Entity>
 <ProcessName>StepOne</ProcessName>
</Entity>
```

The value of input XML tag should be a tag in output XML.

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    Entity: {
        (payload.entity.*element map {
            ($.elementName) : $.elementValue
        })
    }
}
```

Mine output is like

```
<Entity>
  <ProcessName>StepOne</ProcessName>
  <ProcessName1>StepTwo</ProcessName1>
</Entity>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{

  Entity: {
            payload.entity.element.elementName: payload.entity.element.elementValue
          }
}
```

I did a workaround like having an empty tag and replaced that empty tag with sub XML string assigned to a variable. But I would like to achieve this using transformer.